# How to transform earth-centered to topocentric-horizon in c#?

Tags: c#, coordinate

What is the equation/algorithm for transforming ***Earth-Centered Inertial*** (ECI) frame to ***Topocentric-Horizon system*** (SEZ) in `c#`? Can anyone help me?

`X=4, Y=6, Z=10, phi=40, theta= 49`

Comment: Do you really think this has anything to do with `c#` or programming in general?

Comment: [This might help](https://epsg.io/9836-method) (using formulas in [method 9602](https://epsg.io/9602-method))

Comment: @Rafalon if I get formula, I'll do